# How to add a class to the body when parent ID is matched in Kentico 6

Tags: asp.net, kentico

I'm trying to add a `class` to the `body` if **any** parent of the current document matches specified **nodeid**.

For example:

If current document parent **nodeid** is equal to 1234 - add class "blue"

```
<body class="LTR Gecko Gecko28 ENUS ContentBody blue">
```

I it possible to achive this by using macros in webpart settings, not by editing asp?

Comment: Hi, just wanted to ask, if it worked, or if you found a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

It is not a nice solution, but it would is possible *(i would look into asp.net, or custom macros)*

```
//depence when you load jQuery the window.onload = ... , could be replaced with $(...)
{%CurrentDocument.NodeId|(equals)1234|(truevalue)<script>window.onload = function()$("body").addClass("blue");}</script>|(falsevalue)#%}
//Watchout for special-characters in the script, since it could break, the macro
```

*Beware if you upgrade this solution, the code will be altered.*

**Tested with Kentico v6.0.58 (SP1), in a Rich-Text Field and Chrome 33+**